# Trying to find the count of units(objects) in an image

Tags: python, image-processing, computer-vision

So, I have this image where i need to find the count of objects present in the image. What I have done till now is extract the template of object from that image and do the template matching throughout the image. By doing this I have got output matrix which consists of high intensity values where correlation is high. But now the problem is to get the count of the those local peaks. I have tried peak_local_max of scikit and thresholding but I am not able to find satisfying result. For the reference, I am attaching image. [Image in which number of units to be count](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JYWkQ.png)

Comment: try to be more specific and send some code you have done, you should be able to do it using, openCV, or scikit-image...

Comment: Is the answer `1` for that image?